# Access to a Public Variable in another class / folder

Tags: c#, winforms

**I am trying to access to a public static variable in a class** but I don't know how to do it. I try different solutions like using and namespace but doesn't work.

In the form called "CategoriasCaracteristicas.cs" (blue), I am trying to access to empresaGlobal.cs (red) as you can see in the next image:

[image]

But I can't do it using namespace, or others. The **code** of the file "CategoriasCaracteristicas.cs" that is where I am trying to access the other class is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using Utils;


namespace imlnet
{
    public partial class CategoriasCaracteristicas : Form
    {
        private string codEmp;
        private string cadenaConexion;

        public CategoriasCaracteristicas()
        {
```

And this is the **code of empresaGlobal**.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ImeApps
{
    public static class empresaGlobal
    {
        public static string empresaID = "3";

        public static String EmpresaID
        {
            get { return empresaID; }
            set { empresaID = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: empresaGlobal.cs is listed under Solution Items, which means it's not in a project. it needs to be in a project, and then the GestorCategoriasCaracteristicasInjenieria project needs a reference to the other project. (or add empresaGlobal.cs to that project).

Comment: Sorry, I'm starting with C#... So how could I do this? is there a way to do it where can see it?

Comment: `empresaGlobal` is situated inside `namespace ImeApps` I see that you have a project called like the namespace. Why don't you put the empresaGlobal.cs inside that project?

Comment: I believe he can add the different projects as references to each other as necessary so he can access the properties and methods inside. I did a bit of work a few months ago on a project like this which compiled multiple DLL files and referenced those DLLs as a part of the solution as a whole. Something like this may work.

Comment: @MongZhu hi again :) I have to use the class called empresaGlobal in all the other ones, so I have to use it in ImeApps, Aprovisionamiento, Buscador ...

Comment: @JoelTrauger can I see an example of that?

Comment: " I have to use the class called empresaGlobal in all the other ones" then you need to make sure that the reference is included to the ImeApps project in all those projects that need it. Don't forget to write also `using ImeApps`. Or do you want to avoid to reference the entire ImeApps project in the other projects? then you might consider to create an own dll for it with its own namespace and put it in there

Comment: @MongZhu so the best way to do this could be create a project, insert there the class and then add a reference in ImeApps?

Comment: @LuckWallace It took me a minute to make an example but something like this might work. Be sure and make the methods/properties you want to access public or you will not be able to access them. See link: https://imgur.com/a/TeXsByZ

Comment: Thank you for your time @JoelTrauger I am trying it like you are doing in this example but "empresaGlobal does not exist in the current context". What I've done is create a new project called empresaGlobalProj that contains a class called empresaGlobal.cs

Comment: @LuckWallace That should work, just make sure any classes, methods and properties are public so they can be accessed by other projects. If you'd like I can put this in an answer.

Comment: @LuckWallace did you add the reference to "empresaGlobalProj" inside the project where you want to use `empresaGlobal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your **empresaGlobal.cs** file in a project and add that project as a reference to the **GestorCategoriasCaracteristicasIngenieria** project.

Make sure any classes, properties and methods you need to access are available using the `public` keyword.